# Retornar uma lista dos values presentes no select

Tags: javascript, html

Eu fiz uma interface aonde o usuário digita um numero e ele é logo atribuído a um *value* do *select*. A ideia é de que o usuário digite um numero e não possa digitá-lo novamente, porém para isso, eu preciso que em cada chamada da função, seja retornada uma lista dos *values* presentes no *select*, e não estou conseguindo.

O código JavaScript que eu tentei e até agora não deu certo:

```js
function validarNumero() {
    let numeroInput = Number(document.getElementById('inNumero').value)
    let tabela =  document.getElementById('numerosAnotados')
    let numeros = Array.from(tabela)

    if (numeros.indexOf(numeroInput) == -1) { // -1 == Não tem
      numeros.push(numeroInput) // Criando um registro
      let item = document.createElement('option')
      item.text = numeroInput
      tabela.appendChild(item)
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <p>Digite um numero [1 - 100]: <input type="number" name="" id="inNumero">
        <input type="button" value="Adicionar" onclick="validarNumero()"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p><select id="numerosAnotados" size="10"></select><br>
        <input type="button" value="excluir" onclick="excluir()">
    </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de resolver o teu problema seria criar um array global que registaria todos os números que já foram inseridos no select e depois só precisarias verificar se o número já está ou não neste array.

Desta forma:

```
const numerosInseridos = []; // Array de Números Inseridos
function validarNumero() {
    let numeroInput = Number(document.getElementById("inNumero").value);
    let tabela = document.getElementById("numerosAnotados");
    let numeros = Array.from(tabela);
    if (numerosInseridos.includes(numeroInput)  || parseInt(numeroInput) > 100 ||  parseInt(numeroInput) < 0) {// Verificando se o número já foi inserido
        return;
    }
    numeros.push(numeroInput); // Criando um registro
    numerosInseridos.push(numeroInput); // Registando um número já inserido
    let item = document.createElement("option");
    item.text = numeroInput;
    tabela.appendChild(item);
}
```